# Segmentation fault while accessing other GTK widgets in a callback

Tags: c, gtk, gnome

To access other widgets in a callback, I packed them in a structure defined as follows:

```
typedef struct SettingsModel
{
    bool SyncEn;
    int DeviceId;
    int MeasurementId;
    GtkWidget *measurement_type_box;
    GtkWidget *sync_switch;
    GtkWidget *device_type_box;
} SettingsModel;
```

The aim is to update the settings when the save button is clicked. The relevant code snippets:

```
static void click_save(GtkButton *self, gpointer user_data)
{
    SettingsModel *local_data = user_data;
    local_data->DeviceId = gtk_combo_box_get_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(local_data->device_type_box));
    local_data->MeasurementId = gtk_combo_box_get_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(local_data->measurement_type_box));
    local_data->SyncEn = gtk_switch_get_active(GTK_SWITCH(local_data->sync_switch));
}
```

```
save_settings_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Save");
reset_settings_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Reset");
SettingsModel settings;
settings.device_type_box = device_type_box; 
settings.measurement_type_box = measurement_type_box;
settings.sync_switch = sync_enabled_switch;

g_signal_connect(save_settings_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(click_save), &settings);
g_signal_connect(reset_settings_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(click_reset), &settings);
```

However, when I click on the save button, I receive the following errors:

```
(gui:28351): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:52:26.673: invalid cast from 'GdkButtonEvent' to 'GtkComboBox'

(gui:28351): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:52:26.673: gtk_combo_box_get_active: assertion 'GTK_IS_COMBO_BOX (combo_box)' failed
zsh: segmentation fault  ./gui
```

It seems that either the structure was initialized wrongly or GTK somehow thinks that the callback should take a GdkButtonEvent?

Minimal reproducible example here:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

enum 
{
    COL_ID = 0,
    COL_NAME,
    NUM_COLS
};

typedef struct SettingsModel
{
    bool SyncEn;
    int DeviceId;
    int MeasurementId;
    GtkWidget *measurement_type_box;
    GtkWidget *sync_switch;
    GtkWidget *device_type_box;
} SettingsModel;

static void click_save(GtkButton *self, gpointer user_data)
{
    SettingsModel *local_data = user_data;
    local_data->DeviceId = gtk_combo_box_get_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(local_data->device_type_box));
    local_data->MeasurementId = gtk_combo_box_get_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(local_data->measurement_type_box));
    local_data->SyncEn = gtk_switch_get_active(GTK_SWITCH(local_data->sync_switch));
}

static void click_reset(GtkButton *btn_reset, gpointer user_data)
{
    SettingsModel *local_data = user_data;
    local_data->DeviceId = 0;
    local_data->MeasurementId = 0;
    local_data->SyncEn = false;
    gtk_switch_set_active(GTK_SWITCH(local_data->sync_switch), FALSE);
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(local_data->device_type_box), 0);
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(local_data->measurement_type_box), 0);
}

static void app_activate(GApplication *app, gpointer *user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *win;
    GtkWidget *grid;

    g_assert(GTK_IS_APPLICATION(app));
    win = gtk_application_window_new(GTK_APPLICATION(app));
    grid = gtk_grid_new();

    GtkWidget *device_type_box;
    GtkWidget *measurement_type_box;
    GtkWidget *save_settings_button;
    GtkWidget *reset_settings_button;
    GtkWidget *sync_enabled_switch;
    GtkListStore *list_store_device;
    GtkListStore *list_store_measurement;
    GtkCellRenderer *column;

    list_store_device = gtk_list_store_new(NUM_COLS, G_TYPE_INT, G_TYPE_STRING);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(list_store_device, NULL, -1, COL_ID, 0, COL_NAME, "foo", -1);
    device_type_box = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(list_store_device));
    g_object_unref(list_store_device);
    column = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(device_type_box), column, TRUE);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(device_type_box), column,
                                "text", 1,
                                NULL);
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(device_type_box), 0);
    
    list_store_measurement = gtk_list_store_new(NUM_COLS, G_TYPE_INT, G_TYPE_STRING);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(list_store_measurement, NULL, -1, COL_ID, 0, COL_NAME, "foo", -1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(list_store_measurement, NULL, -1, COL_ID, 0, COL_NAME, "bar", -1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(list_store_measurement, NULL, -1, COL_ID, 0, COL_NAME, "something", -1);
    measurement_type_box = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(list_store_measurement));
    g_object_unref(list_store_measurement);
    gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(measurement_type_box), column, TRUE);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(measurement_type_box), column,
                                "text", 1,
                                NULL);
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(measurement_type_box), 2);

    save_settings_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Save");
    reset_settings_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Reset");

    sync_enabled_switch = gtk_switch_new();

    SettingsModel settings;
    settings.device_type_box = device_type_box; 
    settings.measurement_type_box = measurement_type_box;
    settings.sync_switch = sync_enabled_switch;

    g_signal_connect(save_settings_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(click_save), &settings);
    g_signal_connect(reset_settings_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(click_reset), &settings);

    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), device_type_box, 1, 1, 1, 1);    
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), measurement_type_box, 1, 2, 1, 1);  
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), sync_enabled_switch, 1, 3, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), reset_settings_button, 4, 4, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), save_settings_button, 5, 4, 1, 1);

    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(win), grid);

    gtk_widget_show(win);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int stat;

    app = gtk_application_new("simon.app", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(app_activate), NULL);
    stat = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);
    return stat;
}
```

Comment: My interpretation of the error message is that `local_data->device_type_box` or `local_data->measurement_type_box` is a `GdkButtonEvent` instead of a `GtkComboBox`. Maybe you initialize the structure with wrong widget types or maybe the pointer to the structure is wrong. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: Hi, I've added the example to the question. Thanks in advance! @Bodo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing illegal memory because you are passing the address of a non-static object to your callback:

```c
static void app_activate(GApplication *app, gpointer *user_data)
{
...
    SettingsModel settings;

    g_signal_connect(save_settings_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(click_save), &settings);
    g_signal_connect(reset_settings_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(click_reset), &settings);
...
}
```

When your signal handlers are called, the function `app_activate` has already returned to the caller and `settings` is no longer valid.
You must provide address of some static memory object or you need to dynamically allocate memory for your settings.

I would suggest to change definition of `settings` to `static SettingsModel settings;`

Comment: That worked wonders! Thanks for pointing that out. I totally forgot that ```settings``` was initialized in a function.

Comment: @Simon48 That does not mean that is the right way to resolve your problem. Your code is almost always wrong if you need to use `static`......almost always and NOT always.

Comment: @Michi In what way would another option to make the data be available during whole lifetime be more appropriate? Do you see any benefit of making that variable global or use dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: I am definitely not against the `static` keyword, but the program flow should not need to use `static` to work. This is not how GTK should work at all.

Comment: @Michi you might provide an own answer with an improved mechanism to provide required data to the signal handlers and other callbacks

Comment: I am not going to make a discussion about this because it will land in Off topic. Any way, the OPs code clearly shows that the whole program is a mess. It should be done separated into functions and if still gets complicate, then `g_object_set_data_full` is a better choice, but this is my own opinion. As log as the Op uses this program with that struct, complicates the things too much, and yes static is something which does the job there.